# how to define friendly URL for PrestaShop non-core pages

Tags: prestashop

The friendly URLs are stored in the database for all the pages where they are used, but how would I define a friendly URL for this page:

```
http://www.vintage-adventures.com/en/modules/faq/faqs.php
```

so that it serves as (and links TO it look like) this:

```
http://www.vintage-adventures.com/en/modules/faq/faqs
```

Unlike all the other PS core pages, I don't know where the link_rewrite value would STORED and ACCESSED by PS so that this page/link behaves just like all the other friendly URL pages/links. I realize that AFTER it is defined in the database, then I would make a rewrite rule entry in .htaccess so that browsers will fetch the actual content from the non-friendly address. I need to get it DEFINED first, though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually its within the Tools > CMS section there is the meta tags and URL if I am not mistaken...

Answer (score 0):

In prestashop 1.4 you can set this under 
Preferences > SEO & URLs in admin.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a file in root called faq.php with the following code:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/modules/faq/faqs.php');
```

Then SEO & URL tab should pick up faq.php in root which can be given a friendly URL.

Once assigned a friendly URL regenerate an ".htaccess"